# Knockout JS option binding special symbols

Tags: html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

i have array

self.CompareSignArray = ko.observableArray(["&gt", "&le"]);

and select option

```
 <select data-bind="options:  $root.CompareSignArray,value: Sign" ></select>
```

but in dropdown i see  &gt &le, but i want see "> " and ≤
what solve of problem

Comment: you're missing a semicolon.... `&gt;`, `&le;`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the characters you to the array:

```
self.CompareSignArray = ko.observableArray([">", "≤"]);
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/V4GvT/

**HTML**:

```
<select data-bind="options:  CompareSignArray" ></select>
```

**JS**:

```
function viewmodel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.CompareSignArray = ko.observableArray([">", "≤"]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's JS. Use regular characters like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JHv48/1/):

```
self.CompareSignArray = ko.observableArray([">", "<"]);
```